# Trapezoid rule error seems to be 1/N instead of 1/N^2

Tags: algorithms

I'm not sure this should go to Math or Programming sections, but I think mathematicians know programming more often then programmers know mathematics I decided to post here.

I was playing (programming) with Trapezoid rule for integration and noticed some inconsistencies with theory. Wikipedia says that the error for trapezoid rule is ~ 1/N^2.
But in my simulations I find that it's ~1/N. Where N is the number of pieces dividing whole interval. (number of steps)

Having a function $2+Cos(2\sqrt{x})$ the integral from 0 to 2 is : **3.46**.
I made some simulations for trapezoid rule and this is the table for error (Computed - 3.46)

1.87615 (N=2)

0.975054 (N=4)

0.496801 (N=8)

0.250722 (N=16)

0.125942 (N=32)

0.0631172 (N=64)

All these values are about half smaller than previous one. So it seems like error is ~1/N.

I'm quite sure my algorithm is correct, I could paste code if needed.

EDIT:
The code in C++ I was using:

```
double dx = (end_val - start_val) / N;
double xi = start_val+dx;
double sum = 0;
sum += 1 / 2 * (func(start_val) + func(end_val));

for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++)
{
    sum += func(xi);
    xi += dx;
}

sum = dx*sum;
```

where func is:

```
double func(double x)
{
    return (2 + cos(2 * sqrt(x)));
}
```

EDIT: I did a lot of logical as well as C++ specific mistakes (used 1/2 instead of 0.5 and anything that was added to that was interpreted as int therefore 0). Thanks guys.

Comment: Are you sure you used the trapezoidal rule (1/N^2) and not the method based on rectangles (1/N) ? Please post the code.

Comment: For $N=64$ I get an error of $0.000145$.

Comment: Your figures look wrong to me. For instance, I can't reproduce your 1.87615. My computed value is $\frac12 (2+\cos 0) + (2 + \cos 2) + \frac12(2 + \cos 2\sqrt 2) \approx 3.608$, for an error $\approx 0.142$.

Comment: By the way, if anybody is wondering whether it is legitimate to give the error to seven decimal places (0.0631172) when the target value is only given to two decimal places (3.46): yes it is here, at least to five places anyway, because the target value is actually $\approx 3.45999767$.

Comment: Please look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is here:

```
sum += 1 / 2 * (func(start_val) + func(end_val));
```

This always evaluates to zero. Can you see why? If not, I suggest you do some experimenting to try and find out for yourself. That way you won't make the same mistake again!